# HABTM cakephp and saving

Tags: cakephp, associations

hi all I'm trying to create a registration page where a person creates an account, then creates a user. The account can have multiple users and a user can have 0 or 1 accounts. The problem I'm getting with my current code is that account_id isnt loading from a select box

the user can have 0 or 1 account
the account have 1 or many users

my table schema is

users -`id, username, firstname, lastname`
accounts - `id, companyname`
accounts_users -`id, account_id, user_id`

accounts model

```
<?php

class Account extends AppModel{

    var $name='Account';
    public $useTable = 'accounts';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'User' =>
            array(
                'className'=>'User',
                )
            );
```

users model

```
 class User extends AppModel{ 

        public $name = 'User';
        public $useTable = 'users';
        public $primaryKey = 'id';
        var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
            'Account' =>
                array(
                    'className'=>'Account',
                    'joinTable'=>'accounts_users'
                    ));
```

add function is the accounts controller

```
function add(){
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Account registration');
        $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'style');
        $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogo.jpg');   

        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $this->Account->create(); 
            if ($this->Account->save($this->request->data)){
                $this->Session->setFlash('The user has been saved');
                $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'Users','action' => 'addAdmin'));
            }
            else{ 
                $this->Session->setFlash('The business could not be saved. Please, try again.');
                } 
        }
        }
```

the users addAdmin function

```
function addAdmin(){
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Please Login');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'style');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogo.jpg');   
if($this->request->is('post')){
$this->User->create(); 
$this->set('accounts', $this->User->Account->find('list'));
if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) 
{ 
    $this->Session->setFlash('The user has been saved');  
    $this->redirect( array('controller'=>'Users','action' => 'login')); 
}
else { $this->Session->setFlash('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'); } 
}
```

}

the addAdmin form

```
<h2>Welcome please add your Administrator Details</h2>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action'=>'add'));
echo $this->Form->input('Account');
echo $this->Form->input('username',array('label'=>'Username: '));
echo $this->Form->input('password',array('label'=>'Password: '));
echo $this->Form->input('password_confirmation',array('type'=>'password'));
echo $this->Form->input('email',array('label'=>'Email: '));
echo $this->Form->input('title',array('label'=>'Title: '));
echo $this->Form->input('firstname',array('label'=>'First Name: '));
echo $this->Form->input('surname',array('label'=>'Surname: '));
echo $this->Form->input('street',array('label'=>'Street Address: '));
echo $this->Form->input('city',array('label'=>'City: '));
echo $this->Form->input('state',array('label'=>'State: '));
echo $this->Form->input('country',array('label'=>'Country: '));
echo $this->Form->input('access_level', array('default' => 2));
echo $this->Form->end('Add Administrator');

?>
```

Comment: "account_id isnt loading from a select box" could you describe exactly what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in comments, the error is not described clearly. Here is a first answer, I will update/correct it should the answer be ever updated.

The error may be in the controller:

```
function addAdmin(){
$this->set('title_for_layout', 'Please Login');
$this->set('stylesheet_used', 'style');
$this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogo.jpg');  

if($this->request->is('post')){
$this->User->create(); 
$this->set('accounts', $this->User->Account->find('list'));//this line is wrong
if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) 
{ 
    $this->Session->setFlash('The user has been saved');  
    $this->redirect( array('controller'=>'Users','action' => 'login')); 
}
else { $this->Session->setFlash('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'); } 
}
```

The set function is not always called as hidden behind a if. Try:

```
 function addAdmin(){
$this->set('title_for_layout', 'Please Login');
$this->set('stylesheet_used', 'style');
$this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogo.jpg');   
$this->set('accounts', $this->User->Account->find('list'));//moved

if($this->request->is('post')){
$this->User->create(); 
if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) 
{ 
    $this->Session->setFlash('The user has been saved');  
    $this->redirect( array('controller'=>'Users','action' => 'login')); 
}
else { $this->Session->setFlash('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'); } 
}
```

Comment: awesome! fixed my problem however is it possible to load the business' abn?